# Angular 2 - Service with BehaviorSubject creating a loop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, behaviorsubject

I have a nested component that contains a clickable chart with three selectable sections that will set the selectedIndex of the md-tab-group that it is in. I click on the first, I go to first tab, the second leads to the second, and third the third tab, pretty straightforward.

The problem is that the service I'm using seems to be creating some sort of loop. When I console the steps the service is taking I see it getting bigger every time.

Relevant Service code:

```
  changeActiveTab(number) {
    console.log("Before: ");
    this._activeTab.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    this._activeTab.next(number);
    console.log("After");
    this._activeTab.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
```

What I see when I click on the first section, navigate back to the chart with the main nav, and repeat the process two more times:

```
Before:
0
1
After
1
Before:
1
2
2
2
After:
2
Before:
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
After
3
```

I'm pretty new to BehaviorSubject's, any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

(My example that I used was from [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XqwwUM44NQEpxQVFFxNW?p=preview) if that helps any)

Relevant code for parent component:

```
 selectedTab: number;
  subscription:Subscription;
  constructor( private _activeTabService: ActiveTabService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._activeTabService.activeTab$.subscribe(
        selectedTab => this.selectedTab = selectedTab);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Relevant Chart TS for the child component:

```
  onClick(event){
    if(event.series == 'Table'){
      this.changeActiveTab(1);
    }
    if(event.series == 'Chairs'){
      this.changeActiveTab(2);
    }        
    if(event.series == 'Desks'){
      this.changeActiveTab(3);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right.
changeActiveTab does create more and more subscription on every call.
the service should not make the subscription.
the service should have two methods.
1. setTab - will call subject.next with the relevant parameter.
2 register - return an observable of that subject.

exmaple:

```
export class tabService {
subject  = new Subject(); 
setTab(value: string)
   this.subject.next(value);
}

registerTab(){
return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

in my component:

```
myfunction(){
   this.tabService.registerTab().subscribe(
   (res) => do what you want with this value....
);

changeTab(value: string)
{
   this.tabService.setTab(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming! Could you explain what this would look like? If I am setting the tab and returning it isn't that more or less the same as what I have now?

Comment: I added a simple example

Comment: Does it matter that I was using BehaviorSubject in my example and you're using Subject here?
So would my onClick function look something like: 
  `onClick(event){

  this.tabService.registerTab().subscribe(
   (res) => {
    if(event.series == 'Table'){
      this.changeActiveTab(1);
    }
    if(event.series == 'Chairs'){
      this.changeActiveTab(2);
    }        
    if(event.series == 'Desks'){
      this.changeActiveTab(3);
    }
     
   }
  }`

Comment: I am not sure you need behavior subject but it's up to you, the implementation stays the same.